# ObjectOutputStream doesn't correctly save fields of superclasses unless they're Serializable, why no error or warning?

Tags: java, serialization

Say I have an `ArrayList<B>` `array` of objects from a certain class `B`, which extends `A`. `B` has an instance field `bb` and `A` a field `aa`. I know that saving `array` to a .dat-file using `ObjectOutputStream` requires that `B` (not just `ArrayList`!) implement `Serializable`. I've found, however, that when loading the object back from the file (using an `ObjectInputStream`):

```
 arrayLoaded = (ArrayList<B>)myObjIn.readObject();
```

the loaded array isn't identical to the original array: In the particular case, `arrayLoaded.get(0).bb` has the same value as in `array`, but `arrayLoaded.get(0).aa` is "zeroed". It has a default initialization value, regardless of its value when `array` was saved to file. However, this problem is solved by letting also `A` implement `Serializable`.

What bothers me is that this error is so subtle: no exception, no warning (in eclipse), nothing. Is there a reason for this or is this simply an oversight by the java developers? Do I just have to accept it and think hard about which classes in the hierarchy implement `Serializable` every time I want to use object IO streams?

Comment: Somewhere a non-serialisable class has to be extended (even if it's jlo). The no-arg construct of the most derived non-serialisable class is executed during deserialisation.

Comment: Because it is not an error. It is working as specified. See the Object Serialization Specification. That is the *meaning* of implementing/not implementing Serializable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `B` implements `Serializable`, that does not retroactively include the fields of the non-serializable superclass in what gets serialized. (This makes sense, especially when you consider that being able to serialize private and package-private fields of any class just by extending it and implementing `Serializable` would violate its encapsulation.)

A field declared in `A` will behave the same as a field declared as `transient` in `B`. There is a workaround however. From the documentation for [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the
>   subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state
>   of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package
>   fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class
>   it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the
>   class's state.

So you will need to implement `writeObject` and `readObject` in `B` to handle the serialization/deserialization of `A.aa`.

Comment: Would you say other serialization alternatives, say Google Json or Xtream are more convenient?

Answer (score 2):

> What bothers me is that this error is so subtle: no exception, no warning (in eclipse), nothing. Is there a reason for this or is this simply an oversight by the java developers?

It is by design.  (See @Paul Bellora's answer).  The alternatives would be to:

- Make it illegal to declare a class Serializable unless its superclass is Serializable.  That's obviously unworkable.
- Automatically serialize the superclasses fields which breaks if the should or can't be serialized.  (Note that we can't rely on `transient` here, because if the designer of the superclass didn't intend the it to be serializable, he/she won't have labelled the fields.)

> Do I just have to accept it and think hard about which classes in the hierarchy implement Serializable every time I want to use object IO streams?

Basically, yes.  In particular, you need to think hard when you write a Serializable subclass of an existing non-Serializable class.

I guess it is possible to write FindBugs / PMD / etc rules to flag this particular usage as *potentially* problematic.